# Why is my Google Chrome omnibox squishy?

Tags: google-chrome

Sometimes when I'm typing in the omnibox at the top of Chrome I can't read the autocomplete because it starts displaying a weird compressed screenshot. What's going on?
[image]

Comment: It's likely that this is being caused by an extension you recently installed. Would you mind providing a list and/or screenshots of the extensions you currently have installed?

Comment: AngularJS Batarang 0.7.4
Chrome to Mobile 3.1
ColorPick Eyedropper 0.0.2.7
feedly 34
goo.gl URL Shortener 0.7.8
Google Docs 0.7
Google Keep - notes and lists 2.0.14505.1365
Google Mail Checker 4.4.0
Google Play Music 1.249.0
Google Voice (by Google) 2.4.4
Hangouts 2014.1119.433.4
HelloSign for Gmail 1.1.56
Honey 4.0.18
InvisibleHand 3.9.45
Knockoutjs context debugger 2.6.3
LastPass: Free Password Manager 3.1.75
lipsum.com extension 2.0.1
PageSpeed Insights (by Google) 2.0.4.3
Speed Tracer (by Google) 0.27
Web Developer 0.4.6